# After Update Trigger & Concatenation

Tags: t-sql

I haven't used triggers before so this is a 'working' first stab at what I need to achieve.
Once I enter the Value 'V' or 'AV' in the VCODE field the trigger populates the required values for VSYS, SITE_CODE, VAREA & then concatenates these values into the ASSET_TAG field.

I don't think this is the most efficient way to perform this operation, so could somebody out there in SQL land please take a look at my messy script and advise on the most effective method to achieve the same outcome.

Thanks

```
Trigger [dbo].[trValve]    
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
Create trigger [dbo].[trValve] on [dbo].[Valve]
after update
as

Begin
set nocount on;
update Valve Set VSYS = 'VLV'
from Valve t  
inner join inserted i on  t.pkID = i.pkID 
and i.VCODE='V' or 
i.VCODE = 'AV'

Begin
set nocount on;
update Valve 
Set SITE_CODE = '00123'
from Valve t  
inner join inserted i on  t.pkID = i.pkID 
and i.VCODE='V' or 
i.VCODE = 'AV'

Begin
set nocount on;
update Valve 
Set VAREA = 'INL'
from Valve t  
inner join inserted i on  t.pkID = i.pkID 
and i.VCODE='V' or 
i.VCODE = 'AV'

Begin
set nocount on;
update VALVE 
SET ASSET_TAG = CONCAT(Valve.SITE_CODE,'-',Valve.VAREA,'-',   valve.VSYS,'-',Cast (pkID As Varchar(50)));


End 
End
End
End
End
```

Comment: Also one other thing I should of included in the original post, I have existing records that were added to another version of the Valve table on a project so the VCODE field has been populated prior to the creation of this trigger, is there a way I can get this update trigger to populate the record sets retrospectively on my other project Valve Table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can condense things a bit by combining your first 3 SET statements:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trValve] ON [dbo].[Valve]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Valve
    SET VSYS = 'VLV',
    SITE_CODE = '00123',
    VAREA = 'INL'
    FROM Valve t
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON t.pkID = i.pkID
    WHERE i.VCODE = 'V'
    OR i.VCODE = 'AV'

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE VALVE
    SET ASSET_TAG = CONCAT (
            Valve.SITE_CODE,'-',Valve.VAREA,'-',valve.VSYS,'-',Cast(pkID AS VARCHAR(50))
            );
END
END
```

Comment: Thank you sir I will give this a go.